# Temporarily enable and disable button Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm currently trying to prompt users to pick 6 bottles for a package hence disabling the button if they dont but re-enabling the button if they do. The problem i'm facing is that once the button is disabled, it cant be enabled, are there any more suitable functions to use? Have tried event.preventDefault() to no help as well. My code :

```
var atc = document.getElementsByName("add-to-cart");
const button = document.querySelector('button');
var selects = [...document.getElementsByTagName("select")];
document.onchange = () => {
  const sum = selects.reduce((total, select) => {
    return total + Number(select.selectedOptions[0].value)
  }, 0);

if (sum != 6){
    atc[0].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        event.returnValue = false;
    });
    alert("You are Required to Select a Total of 6 Bottles");       
} 
if(sum == 6 ){
    alert("You have selected 6 bottles");
    atc[0].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        event.returnValue = true;
    });
}

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : Have fixed it by using atc.disabled = true || false 
Source Solution : [Conditionally Enabling and Disabling DOM Elements](https://dzone.com/articles/conditionally-enabling-and-disabling-dom-elements)

```
var atc = document.getElementsByName("add-to-cart");
const button = document.querySelector('button');
var selects = [...document.getElementsByTagName("select")];
document.onchange = () => {
  const sum = selects.reduce((total, select) => {
    return total + Number(select.selectedOptions[0].value)
  }, 0);

if (sum != 6){
    atc[0].disabled = true;
    alert("You are Required to Select a Total of 6 Bottles");       
} 
if(sum == 6 ){
    alert("You have selected 6 bottles");
    atc[0].disabled = false;
}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the button, you can simply use the running total to determine what should happen when the button is clicked.

```
 atc[0].addEventListener('click',function(e){
   if(sum != 6){
      alert("You are Required to Select a Total of 6 Bottles");  
    }
    else{
      //submit or whatater
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Have found an alternative solution by enabling and disabling the button through event.disable = true|| false